# React JS - Infinite Loop issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to add some graphs/barcharts to a react component but keep getting an issue with infinite loops.
I've tried this link I found online but I wasn't able to make it work with my code.
https://alexsidorenko.com/blog/react-infinite-loop/

The input data in this example is static... I just want to verify that the code renders... eventually I'll use dynamic data.

```
const MyComponent = ({ someInput }) => {
  const [state2, setState2] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState2({
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Rainfall",
          backgroundColor: [
            "#B21F00",
            "#C9DE00",
            "#2FDE00",
            "#00A6B4",
            "#6800B4",
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#501800",
            "#4B5000",
            "#175000",
            "#003350",
            "#35014F",
          ],
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56],
        },
      ],
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="search">
      <Bar data={state2} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

BAR COMPONENT (From a react template). If I use the standard Bar component from react-charts it renders ok. It's only when I use this bar component that I get the infinite loop. But I think the issue is with my code and not the component from the template as it's a commercial template that's used on different sites.

```
/* eslint-disable prefer-rest-params */
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

import { barChartOptions } from './config';

const Bar = ({ data, shadow = false }) => {
  const chartContainer = useRef(null);
  const [, setChartInstance] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartContainer && chartContainer.current) {
      if (shadow) {
        Chart.defaults.global.datasets.barWithShadow =
          Chart.defaults.global.datasets.bar;
        Chart.defaults.barWithShadow = Chart.defaults.bar;
        Chart.controllers.barWithShadow = Chart.controllers.bar.extend({
          draw(ease) {
            Chart.controllers.bar.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);
            const {
              chart: { ctx },
            } = this;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)';
            ctx.shadowBlur = 7;
            ctx.shadowOffsetX = 5;
            ctx.shadowOffsetY = 7;
            ctx.responsive = true;
            Chart.controllers.bar.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
            ctx.restore();
          },
        });
      }
      const context = chartContainer.current.getContext('2d');
      const newChartInstance = new Chart(context, {
        type: shadow ? 'barWithShadow' : 'bar',
        options: barChartOptions,
        data,
      });
      setChartInstance(newChartInstance);
    }
  }, [chartContainer, data, shadow]);

  return <canvas ref={chartContainer} />;
};

export default Bar;
```

Comment: Why are you storing static data in a state atom in the first place? Or is there some data loading in that effect you've just elided here?

Comment: I assume you have edited the code since there is hard coded data and the prop isn't used. But this simplified example is fine. Can we see the unedited version?

Comment: setState2 is an array and you are storing object into array and the passing array in the Bar where as Bar accepts the object !

Comment: and what did you mean by infinite loop? does Bar chart increase continuously?

Comment: add the "Bar" component, and as @windowsill said, add the unedited version. without extra information, no one can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Sorry I wasn't clear. I've added the Bar component requested. Note: Bar.js is from a react template called gogo react and is probably fine so I don't want to edit that. I'm sure the issue is in my component. I'm just trying to get it to render correctly on the screen before trying to populate it with real data.